# Two ways of computing $\lim_{a \to 0^+} \left( \frac{1}{(x+ia)^2} - \frac{1}{(x-ia)^2} \right)$ gives contradictory result

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

In this question, we assume that $\lim_{a\to 0^+}$ is implicit.

It is well-known that
$$\frac{1}{x-ia} - \frac{1}{x+ia} = 2\pi i \delta(x),$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta distribution. Differentiating this equation gives
$$\frac{1}{(x+ia)^2} - \frac{1}{(x-ia)^2} = 2\pi i\nabla \delta(x).$$
However, we can also evaluate LHS as
$$\frac{1}{(x+ia)^2} - \frac{1}{(x-ia)^2} = \left( \frac{1}{x+ia} - \frac{1}{x-ia}\right) \left( \frac{1}{x+ia} + \frac{1}{x-ia}\right) \\ = -2\pi i\delta(x) \left( \frac{1}{x+ia} + \frac{1}{x-ia}\right) =0,$$
since substituting $x=0$ to the last factor $\left( \frac{1}{x+ia} + \frac{1}{x-ia}\right)$ gives 0. Since all calculations are done formally, I am not sure which one is correct. Which one is correct, and why?

Finally, the same problem occurs for higher powers. For example, differentiating again gives
$$\frac{1}{(x-ia)^3} - \frac{1}{(x+ia)^3} = \pi i\nabla^2\delta(x),$$
but evaluating LHS as
$$\frac{1}{(x-ia)^3} - \frac{1}{(x+ia)^3} = \left( \frac{1}{x-ia} - \frac{1}{x+ia} \right) \left( \frac{1}{(x-ia)^2} + \frac{1}{(x-ia)(x+ia)}+\frac{1}{(x+ia)^2} \right)$$
gives undefined result $2\pi i\delta(x)/(ia)^2$. Which one is correct?

Comment: It might be well known to you, but can you write down what you define $\delta(x)$ is?

Comment: @QC_QAOA It is Dirac delta distribution.

Comment: See you have done a mistake, $\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x+ia}-\dfrac{1}{x-ia}\bigg)$ is not equal to $2\pi i\delta(x)$

Comment: When you say "substituting $x=0$" you seem to be only taking the limit of half of the expression while not evaluating the other half

Comment: While it is true that in $M(\mathbb{R})=C_c(\mathbb{R})'$ we have $(f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})\mapsto \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)((x+ia)^{-1}-(x-ia)^{-1})\,\mathrm{d}x)$ converges to $2\pi if(0)$ as $a\to 0$, it is not true to say $(1/(x+ia)-1/(x-ia))\to 2\pi i\delta(x)$ if you work in, e.g., $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Let's write $1/(x + i a)$ for the ordinary function/regular distribution and $1/(x + i0)$ for the distributional limit. The derivative of $1/(x + i a)$ is the same in the ordinary sense and in the distributional sense. Since differentiation of distributions is a continuous operation, $1/(x + i0)^2 - 1/(x - i0)^2 = 2 \pi i \delta'(x)$ follows. We can't interchange the limit and the product though, the product of distributions is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is not wrong, but you have to keep in mind that you take the limit $a\rightarrow 0$ after all. I addition your product is in indeterminate form, since plugging in $x=0$ gives something of the form $\infty\cdot 0$.

If you really want to follow the route of factorization, rather than considering $$\frac{1}{(x+ia)^2} - \frac{1}{(x-ia)^2} = \frac{-4ia x}{(x^2+a^2)^2}$$ directly, you have to find out how
$$- \left( \frac{1}{x+ia} + \frac{1}{x-ia} \right) = \frac{-2x}{a^2+x^2}$$ behaves, i.e. how the RHS acts via integration on test-functions and not just point-wise considerations for $x=0$ and $x\neq 0$. Indeed the RHS seems to vanish for $x=0$, but at the same time it has maxima at $x=\pm a$ with the values $\pm \frac{1}{a}$ when $a \rightarrow 0$. So really the RHS as a distribution is indeterminate at $x=0$.

However, you can easily check how this expression behaves on some test-function $f(x)$ (assuming integrals are defined) $$\int \frac{-2x}{a^2+x^2} \, f(x) \, {\rm d}x = \log\left(\frac{a/\pi}{x^2+a^2}\right) f(x) - \int \log\left(\frac{a/\pi}{x^2+a^2}\right) f'(x) \, {\rm d}x \\
\stackrel{a\rightarrow 0}{=}\log(\delta(x)) f(x) - \int \log(\delta(x)) f'(x) \, {\rm d}x = \int \frac{\delta'(x)}{\delta(x)} f(x) \, {\rm d}x$$
which is what you would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then, is it valid to differentiate the distribution as in my question?

Comment: What do you mean? As in $$\frac{-2x}{a^2+x^2} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \log \left( \frac{a/\pi}{x^2+a^2} \right) \, ?$$
Derivatives of distributions can be defined, yes.

Comment: I mean whether the equation $\frac{1}{(x+ia)^2} - \frac{1}{(x-ia)^2} = 2\pi i\nabla \delta(x)$, obtained by formal differentiation is valid, as stated in the question.

Comment: Well, I guess you could define it this way, but eventually what counts is it's action on test-functions via integration and the LHS does exactly what you would expect from the RHS.